# How to pass the phonegap javascript value to android native app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

How to pass the phonegap javascript value to android native app.

Please any help me

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap plugins is the way. Learn about developing a phonegap plugin. With phonegap plugin you can access the Objective C methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass the blow value phonegap to android native app.

```
<script language="javascript">
```

function callTojavaFn() {

var msg = {“amout”:”10”, “txnid”: “1587924”}

var msgString = JSON.stringify(msg)

JsHandler.jsFnCall(msgString);

}